# Calculating probability of an exponential random variable.

Tags: probability-theory, probability-distributions

The time between failures of a particular electronic component has approximately an exponential
distribution with the average of $1200$ hours.Suppose that a circuit is constructed so that two identical components(let's say $C_1$ and $C_2$) operate in parallel
(so that the system fails only if both fail), and their failures occur independently.
What is the probability that this circuit will operate for at least $2000$ hours without a
failure?

So, if I consider $X_1=$ time taken for $C_1$ to fail.

and $X_2=$time taken for $C_2$ to fail.

Here both $X_1$ and $X_2$ are exponential random variable.

Then, we have to find $P(X_1+X_2>2000).$ But I know that $X_1+X_2$ is not an exponential random variable. So, what should I do after that?

Thanks!

Comment: It is not $\Pr(X_1+X_2\gt 2000)$ that you need to compute.

Comment: @AndréNicolas Why?

Comment: Because the random variable we are interested in is $W=\max(X_1,X_2)$, the lifetime of the longer-lived of the two components.

Comment: @AndréNicolas Oh! yes, that's correct. I feel so dumb. Thanks for the clarification.

Comment: You are welcome. An easy mistake to make, sums of random variables occur far more often than the max or min.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I'd look at the complementary event: if the circuit fails before 2000 hours then both components have failed before 2000 hours, and using independence you can calculate these probabilities separately then multiply.